# How to detect values ​that are only composed of numbers?

Tags: r, string, numbers

How to detect values ​​that are only composed of numbers? For example, I have this tibble:

```
example<- tibble(a=c("1234","abc","12c4","5678","3456","dce","456y"),
       b= seq(1:7))

example

 a         b
  <chr> <int>
1 1234      1
2 abc       2
3 12c4      3
4 5678      4
5 3456      5
6 dce       6
7 456y      7
```

and I want it to detect the values ​​1,4 and 5 in the b column, which are the values ​​exclusively composed of numbers. But I don't know how to do it. This doesn't work for me because it also detects mixed values :

```
str_detect(example$a, "[^a-z]")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

I need  to return me this

```
"1234" "5678" "3456"
```

or this

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Ideally I would like to only work with column a, not column b.

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer this option from linked posts: `!is.na(as.numeric(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl`:

```r
grepl("^\\d+$", example$a)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To get the matching values, just subset the column:

```r
example$a[grepl("^\\d+$", example$a)]
[1] "1234" "5678" "3456"
```